# Ошибка JSLint - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jslint

При попытке провалидировать с помощью JSLint следующий код:

```
entry.object.var ? json_obj.var = entry.object.var : json_obj.var = "";
```

я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
```

Здесь я пытаюсь сделать следующее: при значении undefined в `entry.object.var` присваивать значение в JSON ,либо пустое поле.

Вопросы:

1. Можно  ли сделать это красивее?
2. Как правильно оключить это предупреждение? Пробовал 
   `/* jslint expr: true */` но получаю ошибку
       `Unexpected 'expr'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что тернарный оператор возвращает значение, JSLint ожидает что Вы присвоите это значение какой-то переменной, но этого не происходит. Идеологически правильнее в таких случаях не мудрить и использовать if-else.

В вашем случае принято использовать что-то вроде:

```
json_obj.var = entry.object.var || "";
```